# To load the File from the RAR file

Tags: java, io, rar

I try to load the File from RAR . I am using the

```
sFileName=Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("common.xml").getFile();
```

Immediately, my requirement is load the file in to File IO.

```
fSettings = new File(sFileName);
if (fSettings.exists() && fSettings.isFile()) {
```

Is it possible to load the File from classpath and Create File object? Would it be possible to validate?

Share your thoughts.

I get this following error:

> 22:44:16,718 ERROR [STDERR] **java.io.FileNotFoundException:** file:\C:\Servers\ApplicationServers\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\XXXX\tmp\deploy\XXX.ear-contents\XXX.rar!\common.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
>   22:44:16,718 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL that you get with the `getResource()` might not be a file, and in this case it's not because your `common.xml` is inside of a RAR file. If you want to access `common.xml`, just do a `getResourceAsStream()` and read the `InputStream`.

Comment: Hi @Francis Upton, But if read as the InputStream , i couldn't able to convert as File IO.Could you give any Suggestion to Convert as File?

Comment: It's difficult since the object you want is inside of a RAR file; you will have to get the RAR file and process that. There is no separate File object for the member of the RAR file. Why do you need to use File IO with it?

Comment: One option is to read it using the method that I mentioned and then write it to a temp file and use File I/O with that.

Comment: Hi @Francis ,Because, I don't want to break the existing logic.previously we did that from a folder.but now the situation we moved in RAR. From that rare, we want to load the file,but not breaking the code.

Comment: If you don't want to break existing code, then write it to a temp file as I suggested earlier. That's the only easy way.

Comment: You are not writing a a temp *jar* file, just a normal temp file from the XML object.

Comment: And if you like the answer, please upvote and accept it (welcome to Stack Overflow) :)